# Dictionary in c# duplicate key

Tags: c#, wcf, dictionary

I'm developing a WCF service. In this service I need to return an array with each index. But I happen to have a case (can be a lot this case) where 1 index may have one or more data. I explain

I have a class Indicator

```
public class Indicador
{
    [DataMember]
    public string indicador_nombre { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string indicador_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string indicador_tipo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string indicador_descripcion { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, List<Celda>> celdas { get; set; }
}
```

This indicator has a dictionary that contains a `string` and a list of `Celdas`.

```
public class Celda
{
    [DataMember]
    public int celda_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_codigo_empresa { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_modulo_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int celda_orden { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_categoria_nombre { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_categoria_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<CeldaKeyVal> valores_celdas { get; set; }
}
```

`Celda` also has a list of `CeldaKeyVal`

```
public class CeldaKeyVal
{
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_key_codigo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string celda_key_valor { get; set; }
}
```

Now, for example I have the following:

```
{
  "GetCheckInResult": {
    "indicadores": [
      {
        "celdas": [
          {
            "Key": "I001",
            "Value": [
              {
                "celda_categoria_codigo": "C01",
                "celda_categoria_nombre": "Cecina",
                "celda_codigo_empresa": "E0001",
                "celda_id": 1,
                "celda_modulo_codigo": "M01",
                "celda_orden": 1,
                "valores_celdas": [
                  {
                    "celda_key_codigo": "CODIGO",
                    "celda_key_valor": "CHECK1"
                  },
                  {
                    "celda_key_codigo": "IMAGEN",
                    "celda_key_valor": "L76nD.jpg"
                  },
                  {
                    "celda_key_codigo": "SUBTEXTO",
                    "celda_key_valor": "prueba subtexto 1"
                  },
                  {
                    "celda_key_codigo": "TEXTO",
                    "celda_key_valor": "Prueba dominio 1"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "indicador_codigo": "I001",
        "indicador_descripcion": "Foto SKU + Descrip.SKU + EAN13 + Sí/No",
        "indicador_nombre": "Presencia",
        "indicador_tipo": "T01"
      },
      {
        "celdas": [
          {
            "Key": "I002",
            "Value": [
              {
                "celda_categoria_codigo": "C02",
                "celda_categoria_nombre": "Cerdo",
                "celda_codigo_empresa": "E0001",
                "celda_id": 4,
                "celda_modulo_codigo": "M01",
                "celda_orden": 1,
                "valores_celdas": [
                  {
                    "celda_key_codigo": "CODIGO",
                    "celda_key_valor": "codigo"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "indicador_codigo": "I002",
        "indicador_descripcion": "Descrip. + Cantidad",
        "indicador_nombre": "Precio",
        "indicador_tipo": "T03"
      },
      {
        "celdas": [
          {
            "Key": "I002",
            "Value": [
              {
                "celda_categoria_codigo": "C01",
                "celda_categoria_nombre": "Cecina",
                "celda_codigo_empresa": "E0001",
                "celda_id": 5,
                "celda_modulo_codigo": "M01",
                "celda_orden": 4,
                "valores_celdas": [
                  {
                    "celda_key_codigo": "CODIGO",
                    "celda_key_valor": "ssddsds"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "indicador_codigo": "I002",
        "indicador_descripcion": "Descrip. + Cantidad",
        "indicador_nombre": "Precio",
        "indicador_tipo": "T03"
      },
      {
        "celdas": [
          {
            "Key": "I003",
            "Value": [
              {
                "celda_categoria_codigo": "C01",
                "celda_categoria_nombre": "Cecina",
                "celda_codigo_empresa": "E0001",
                "celda_id": 3,
                "celda_modulo_codigo": "M01",
                "celda_orden": 6,
                "valores_celdas": [
                  {
                    "celda_key_codigo": "CODIGO",
                    "celda_key_valor": "sdadsa"
                  },
                  {
                    "celda_key_codigo": "IMAGEN",
                    "celda_key_valor": "L76nD.jpg"
                  },
                  {
                    "celda_key_codigo": "TEXTO",
                    "celda_key_valor": "Texto 1"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "indicador_codigo": "I003",
        "indicador_descripcion": "Foto + Sí/No",
        "indicador_nombre": "Actividades Claves",
        "indicador_tipo": "T02"
      }
    ],
    "status": 1
  }
}
```

If I have to realize the `key I002`, two `Celdas`... then I would like that two `Celdas` were in the same `key` and not separately.

At first I was initializing the dictionary for each iteration of the query result of my SP. but fails and displays an arrangement like that to stop. If I initialize outside my for, ie once, generates multiple results and that if it is wrong. Try to be as specific as possible, any questions do not hesitate to comment!

Comment: The code that populates the dictionary, what does that look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, I found that the error was completely in my code !, a real shame ... I leave the code solution if someone serves you!

```
public ListaCeldas GetCheckList(int gsalid)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Db);
        List<Celda> celdas = new List<Celda>();
        ListaCeldas lista_celdas = new ListaCeldas();
        try
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MBL_SEL_CELDAS", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("gsalid", gsalid);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dtCelda = new DataTable();
            dtCelda.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

            foreach (DataRow dr in dtCelda.Rows)
            {
                Celda celda = new Celda();
                celda.celda_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CeldaId"]);
                celda.celda_codigo_empresa = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaEmpresaCodigo"]);
                celda.celda_modulo_codigo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaModuloCodigo"]);
                celda.celda_orden = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CeldaOrden"]);
                celda.celda_categoria_nombre = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaCategoriaNombre"]);
                celda.celda_categoria_codigo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaCategoriaCodigo"]);
                celda.indicador_nombre = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaIndicadorNombre"]);
                celda.indicador_codigo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaIndicadorCodigo"]);
                celda.indicador_tipo = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaIndicadorTipoCodigo"]);
                celda.indicador_descripcion = Convert.ToString(dr["CeldaIndicadorDescripcion"]);
                DataTable dtCeldasKey = new DataTable();
                SqlCommand cmd_celdas_key = Helper.GetCeldaValoresKey(celda.celda_id);
                dtCeldasKey.Load(cmd_celdas_key.ExecuteReader());
                List<CeldaKeyVal> listaCeldaKey = new List<CeldaKeyVal>();
                foreach (DataRow drCeldasKey in dtCeldasKey.Rows)
                {
                    CeldaKeyVal celda_key_val = new CeldaKeyVal();
                    celda_key_val.celda_key_codigo = Convert.ToString(drCeldasKey["CeldaKeyCodigo"]);
                    celda_key_val.celda_key_valor = Convert.ToString(drCeldasKey["CeldaKeyValue"]);
                    listaCeldaKey.Add(celda_key_val);
                }
                celda.valores_celdas = listaCeldaKey;
                celdas.Add(celda);
                var groupByIndicador = (from celdasClass in celdas
                                        group celdasClass by celdasClass.indicador_codigo
                                            into groupIndicador
                                            select groupIndicador).ToDictionary(cgd => cgd.Key, cgd => cgd.ToList());
                lista_celdas.status = 1;
                lista_celdas.indicadores = groupByIndicador;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            lista_celdas.status = 0;
        }
        return lista_celdas;
    }
```